# Can I concatenate multiple object parameters to form a single string within a ternary operation within html using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array that contains objects that contain name and date values and a boolean. I want to use angularJs ternary operator to display 'approved' + obj.Name + obj.Date w/i a repeat loop.

I've tried a lot of different things including the following but I've found no luck.

```
<div ng-repeat="apr in ApprovalPath">
     <div class="form-group-sm">
          <label>Level {{$index + 1}}{{apr.stepApproved ? ' - Approved by {apr.stepApprovedName} on {apr.stepApprovedDate}' : ''}}</label>
     </div>
<div>
```

apparently no one seems to have ever had to concatenate multiple variables together in a ternary operator before so I haven't been able to find an answer to this question. Obviously I can create a function to do it but it seems overkill as I only need this once. Also it doesn't make sense to need to update the array to include a parameter on each object that is the combination as this is all coming from a database lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="apr in ApprovalPath">
 <div class="form-group-sm">
      <label>Level {{$index + 1}}{{apr.stepApproved ? '- Approved by '+ apr.stepApprovedName +' on '+ apr.stepApprovedDate : ''}}</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but the intellisense was not liking it so I tried some things that looked to parse better and never came back to it. It works though.